# What Does =& Mean?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I've been programming PHP for over 5 years and I've just came across something I have never seen whilst creating a wordpress theme.

```
$images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image' );
```

What does $images =& do? It's the =& I'm concerned about. I have a feeling it's bitwise but I wouldn't understand what it's doing even if it was.

Any help?

Comment: A bad way to write code. It's actually `=  &get_children` (note the space between the two tokens). Given your experience, the `&` you should know.

Comment: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: the bitwise assigment is &= and do a bitwise and beetween the left and rigth part of expression putting the result into the left one

Comment: @Eineki Delete that quick. Before someone notices.

Comment: See also [Returning references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

Comment: @Linus Kleen Now I feel stupid! Just goes to show what happens when people go against convention.

Comment: @Jamie Nah. No need to degrade yourself. There's actually no convention that prohibits you to write that. The parser just goes ahead and says: *Oh neat. Yet another whitespace I don't have to ignore. Cause it's not there! Whooo!*

Comment: @Linus Kleen Why? Is not &= the bitwise assigment as stated in http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php ?

Comment: @Eineki 1 + 1 = 2. This is also a true statement. Yet, it, too, has nothing to do with the question. The question is about `=&` not `&=`.

Answer (score 4):

Assigns a value by reference

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

> Assignment by reference means that
>   both variables end up pointing at the
>   same data, and nothing is copied
>   anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

`=&` is the [assignment by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference) operator.

You can find out more about references here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 1):

It's an assign by reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

As opposed to a normal pass by value assignment.

Comment: No, it's an assignment by reference.

Comment: Thx, you are 100% correct. I stand corrected (and am slapping myself).